# Issue updating the text value for a editable combo

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017, ccombobox

I have a simple editable combo box on my dialog.

It has several predefined text values in the drop list. One of those entries is:

```
"Test 123"
```

The combo box is mapped to a `CString` variable `m_strNotes`.

If I do this:

```
m_strNotes = _T("Test");
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

I find that the combo box ends up with "Test 123" selected!

Instead, I have to use `m_cbTextValues.SetWindowText(_T("Test"));` and kind of bypass using the `m_strNotes` variable.

Why do I have to do this? Since `CComboBox` can be editable, the text does not have to be in the drop list. So when I use the former method why doesn't it just set the edit text and not try to find a suitable match in the drop list data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior you get with `DDX_CBString` which does a prefix string compare for the selection. Rather use `DDX_CBStringExact` for an exact match.

Comment: Wicked! Didn't know that. I assume this can't be adjusted through ClassWizard and that I must manually adjust the code.